# return statement returns None instead of value

Tags: python, procedures

I have run into a weird problem. This code returns None instead of True, even though it goes in to the correct branch and evaluates to True:

```
edges = { (1, 'a') : [2, 3],
          (2, 'a') : [2],
          (3, 'b') : [4, 3],
          (4, 'c') : [5] }
accepting = [2, 5] 
loc = []
def nfsmsim(string, current, edges, accepting): 

    if string != "":
        if ((current, string[0]) in edges.keys()):
            global loc 
            loc = edges[(current, string[0])]
            print "edge found:",loc

    if (string == ""):
        print "string is over",current,accepting
        print type(current), type(accepting)
        if current in accepting : 
            print "1"
            return True
        else: 
            print "2"
            return 2
    # fill in your code here 
    elif (current, string[0]) in edges.keys():
        global loc
        string = string[1:]
        nfsmsim(string, loc[0], edges, accepting)
    elif len(loc)>1:
        global loc
        nfsmsim(string, loc[1], edges, accepting)


# This problem includes some test cases to help you tell if you are on
# the right track. You may want to make your own additional tests as well.
print nfsmsim("abc", 1, edges, accepting)
```

The output of this is :

```
 string is over 5 [2, 5]
<type 'int'> <type 'list'>
1
None (<< instead of True)
```

Comment: You should include your `def` for the function

Comment: Then we would know what you're supposed to be printing/returning!

Comment: There. Updated the question. There is only return statement in the code - a fact that I missed putting in the question.

Comment: Based on the comment we see there in the code, you may also want to tag this as homework (it looks like it is).

Comment: and you should reformat this and let the "print" and "return" staements be in an indented block! The whole language is designed around making code readable - you are going upstream, and o n the wrong lane to make your code unreadable packing statements in a single lime.

Comment: @jsbeuno I do that all the time, except this once.

Comment: I don't see anything in the function that could cause it to ever return `True`. The only `return` statements return `1` and `2`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a recursive function. When you reach the terminal case (`string == ""`), you return `1` or `2`. That gets returned to the calling function -- the previous call of `nfsmsim`. But *that* call of of `nfsmsim` doesn't return anything! You need to get the value from the terminal call of `nfsmsim` and pass it on by returning it again.

In other words, you need a return statement in each of these two branches of your `if` statement:

```
elif (current, string[0]) in edges.keys():
    global loc
    string = string[1:]
    nfsmsim(string, loc[0], edges, accepting)
elif len(loc)>1:
    global loc
    nfsmsim(string, loc[1], edges, accepting)
```

Comment: [redacted] I don't want to give too much away for HW ;)

Comment: @Thr4wn, thanks :) fixxxer, not to be condescending, but you'll probably learn more if you figure out where to put the return statements yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! :) I ended up setting a flag and returning True based on it, at the end of the function. But it doesn't look like the cleanest way to do it.

Comment: @fixxxer, depending on what you want to happen that might be the best way. You _could_ put returns in both of these blocks, because they're separate branches and no code comes after them. But if you want to convert the value or something before returning it, then that might lead to code duplication. (Still, it's most common, in recursive functions, to have the terminal case return the kind of value you want, and then just keep returning it.)

Answer (score 2):

Not using a return command when the function ends is the same as using return None.

As the function is recursive and you are using its result, you must return the value of every of its call also inside its body:

```
elif (current, string[0]) in edges.keys():
    global loc
    string = string[1:]
    return nfsmsim(string, loc[0], edges, accepting)
elif len(loc)>1:
    global loc
    return nfsmsim(string, loc[1], edges, accepting)
```

You should forget about using the global loc.  Just pass it via the argument.  It is a reference anyway:

```
edges = { (1, 'a') : [2, 3],
          (2, 'a') : [2],
          (3, 'b') : [4, 3],
          (4, 'c') : [5] }
accepting = [2, 5] 
loc = []
def nfsmsim(string, current, edges, accepting, loc): 

    if string != "":
        if ((current, string[0]) in edges.keys()):
            loc = edges[(current, string[0])]
            print "edge found:",loc

    if (string == ""):
        print "string is over",current,accepting
        print type(current), type(accepting)
        if current in accepting : 
            print "1"
            return True
        else: 
            print "2"
            return 2
    # fill in your code here 
    elif (current, string[0]) in edges.keys():
        string = string[1:]
        return nfsmsim(string, loc[0], edges, accepting, loc)
    elif len(loc)>1:
        return nfsmsim(string, loc[1], edges, accepting, loc)


# This problem includes some test cases to help you tell if you are on
# the right track. You may want to make your own additional tests as well.
print nfsmsim("abc", 1, edges, accepting, loc)
```

It prints the following on my console:

```
c:\tmp\___python\fixxxer\so10274792>python a.py
edge found: [2, 3]
edge found: [4, 3]
edge found: [5]
string is over 5 [2, 5]
<type 'int'> <type 'list'>
1
True
```